# After getting result , it also mentions the memory location

Tags: python-3.x

```
def is_leap(num):
    if(num % 400 == 0):
        print("The year {} is a leap year".format(num))
    elif(num % 4 == 0 and num % 100!= 0):
        print("The year {} is a leap year".format(num))
    else:
        print("The year {} is not a leap year".format(num))
    return is_leap

year = is_leap(2000)
print(year
```

)

I get the result but it also mentions this - function is_leap at 0x101a581e0
how can I avoid this? I have tried to resolve this myself after googling I found that I am returning my own function but still I am not able to figure it out on which part of the code should I modify

Answer (score 0):

In the function you return 'is_leap', which is the function itself, meaning after `year = is_leap(2000)`, the `year` variable refers to the function itself, and you print that stored value. Since you already print your result inside is_leap(), there is no need for returning something, or for using

```
print(is_leap(x))
```

If you simply remove the return statement from the function and then call it like `is_leap(2000)`
you should achieve what you want.

Comment: If I remove the return statement, it shows an error saying assigning the result of a function call where there is no return statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_leap(num):
    is_leap_year=False
    if(num % 400 == 0):
        is_leap_year=True
        print("The year {} is a leap year".format(num))
    elif(num % 4 == 0 and num % 100!= 0):
        is_leap_year=True
        print("The year {} is a leap year".format(num))
    else:
        print("The year {} is not a leap year".format(num))
    return is_leap_year

year = is_leap(2000)
print(year)
```

I think you want to set boolean either it is leap year or not but you are returning funtion name and printing it which is reference address of function.

Comment: The year 2000 is a leap year
False

Comment: This is the result that I am getting. I want to display only the first line. How can I do that?

Comment: just remove print line at the end of program